# SMTP error while calling mail sending C# exe from Azure pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a C# exe which performs some activity and sending emails, and it is working fine. Now I need to call this exe from the Azure pipeline. So I added a CommandLine script task and called this exe. When I run the pipeline, below errors were logged.

tasksSystem.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP host was not found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:

How can I solve this smtp issue? How can I call an exe from the azure pipeline to send custom messages?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It all depeneds what SMTP server did you use in your app. Without moe details it is difficult to say something more.

But if you want to send an email you can use [Send Email extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&ssr=false#overview) or [SendGrid extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&ssr=false#overview).